# Vue components in user-defined markdown

Tags: javascript, vue.js, markdown

I need to instantiate zero or more Vue components within HTML generated by a markdown rendering plugin. The component count and props for each are defined in the markdown. (I control the markdown plugin.)

```
instead of normal template syntax:
 <my-component :key="uid_var"></my-component>

markdown plugin would generate HTML:
 <div id="uid">replaced by component</div>

which we pass to vue in a template:
 <div v-html="md.render(src, {map:myCompMap})"></div>
```

This article suggests the following
https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/

```
var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(MyComponent);
var instance = new ComponentClass({
    propsData: { input: 'xyz' },
});
instance.$mount('#uid');
```

But this is user-written markdown, re-rendered on every keystroke, so we should re-use component instances. Questions...

1. Do I call `instance.$mount('#uid')` after each `md.render()` pass?
2. Do I call `instance.$destroy()` if a later `md.render()` pass drops a component?
3. Do I need a key attribute in the markdown, e.g. `<div id="uid" key="uid">`? I suspect the above achieves what a key provides in vue templates.